# Comparing edit dates

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm starting with Google Script, and I want to know if there is a way to take the edit date before the file suffers a new edit, and compare both dates.

I.E. : I have a file that was edited on November 3rd. I wanna store this update date on a var, modificate the file, and store the new update date on an other var.

I'm using method .getFileUpdated() to take the last update, but I need a method or anything like that to take and store the date before file suffers an edit.

Thank You

Comment: Please clarify your question before it gets voted down.

Comment: I tried to clarify it, but if it's still not okay, enlighten me

Comment: What do you want to know? Where to store the old modified date so u can compare it later?

Comment: Oh Jesus...Reading it for the third time I saw it's still a mess... Sorry... :(

I wanna know if there is a method or anything like that, that stores the old modified date. How can I store it. 

Clear now?

Answer (score 0):

See "storing data" in the main apps script help page. Basically you will use scriptProperties or scriptDb.

Comment: it didn't work. is there a way to turn a non static data on a static data?

Comment: not clear what you need or what doesnt work, if you dont put the work to explain well I wont either :) storing data works 100%

Comment: I found a way to do what I want using spreadsheet...  I tried your idea, but it went completely wrong. I definately made something wrong. lol

Btw, another question. 

I have a var that searches for an specific file name 
`var planilha = DriveApp.searchFiles('title contains "Edição de arquivo"').hasNext();`

if it returns true, I have to insert data on this spreadsheet. But i don't know how to insert data on this spreadsheet, since it's closed. I worked only with .getActiveSpreadsheet(). 

I guess I have to find this file's id, put on a var and use .getRange(). But how can I take this id?

Comment: Place new comments on new questions. What you are asking is done in a lot of the basic samples in the apps script help.